# Посмотреть код без инструкций препроцессора

Tags: c++, c, препроцессор

Есть ли программа, которая бы как компилятор начинала собирать проект и останавливалась после этапа препроцессора? Чтобы оставался чистый код, как если бы его писали без препроцессорных команд. Хотя было бы неплохо, чтобы в итоге он бы разделял фрагменты кода по именам заголовочных файлов.

Comment: У компилятора есть соответствующие ключики. Каким вы пользуетесь?

Comment: например [ключ `-E`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4900890/2881286) или [`-P` или  все вместе `-EP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979054/2881286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум в gcc (и, соответственно, в его производных, типа minGW) препроцессор — это отдельная программа, которая назвается cpp:

`cpp -o yourfile.c.preprocessed yourfile.c`

Поверьте, один раз прочитав его вывод, вы поймёте, почему фраза "бойтесь своих желаний, они могут сбыться" не лишена смысла :)

Comment: Ну и как код-то получить? Дополни что ли...

Comment: @Qwertiy дополнил.

Comment: В gcc можно и напрямую, `gcc -E`. И да, обычно не так страшен вывод препроцессора, как сообщения об ошибках, которые выдает компилятор.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, ага, вижу :)

Answer (score 1):

До кучи :) - в Visual C++ ключ `/P` создаст файл с тем же именем и расширением `.i` (можно изменить с помощью ключа `/Fi`), в который будут включены имена включаемых файлов и номера строк.

В OpenWatcom `-pl` выведет информацию в `stdout`, для вывода в файл надо либо перенаправить вывод, либо указать имя с помощью ключа `-fo`.